# How to link a schedule with a runbook in Azure Automation Account

Tags: javascript, php, azure, azure-powershell

Does any one know how to link a schedule with a runbook with Rest API in Azure Automation Account, I can do it very easily with powershell with the following code but don't find a Rest API for the same.

```
#Link Schedule to a runbook

Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook `
-AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccount `
-Name $runbookName `
-ScheduleName $mys `
-ResourceGroupName $rg
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try using the `-Debug` flag and look at the REST calls the actual cmdlet uses

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK currently there is no supported REST API to link schedule to runbook. If interested, you may share it as feature request in feedback.azure.com. As a workaround, you may try below provided unsupported REST API.

REST API:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/xxxxxxxxxx/jobSchedules/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2015-10-31
```

BODY:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "parameters": {},
    "runbook": {
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "schedule": {
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "runOn": ""
  }
}
```